# Get windows with same process name but different pid in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have know how to **get pid from same application process**

```
set pidList to the unix id of (every process whose name contains "MyApplication")
```

The pidList will get all the process id which have same process name "MyApplication"

> How can I get different window with pid that gotten before?

T**he windows have same name "MyApplication Window"** ,so I can't use below simply.

**The application is open by cmd `open -n`(Separate instances of the same application)**

eg:

```
set position of window "MyApplication Window" of (application process whose unix id is theItem) to {39, 578}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have shown no context in which the code in your question is implemented. You really should conform your question to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's hard to describe this example. you should knew applescript first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding a second answer as I gather now what you wish to achieve is to obtain references to the windows that belong to separate, concurrently running instances of a single application, opened using `open -n` from *Terminal*

So I just went ahead and did the same thing.  I launched a second instance of *Script Editor* from *Terminal*, and each of them have a window called "Untitled".  I've opened up another document in one of the instances (so one instance has two windows, and the other has just one).  I've retrieved the windows of both instances like this:

```
    tell application "System Events" to get every window of ¬
        (every process whose name is "Script Editor")

        --> {{window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events", ¬
              window "Import To Photos" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events"}, ¬
             {window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events"}}
```

It returns a list, but inside this list are nested **two** separate lists—one for each instance of *Script Editor*—and inside those lists are the windows belonging to each instance.  As you'd expect, one list has one item (because on instance of the application has just a single window, called "Untitled"), and the other list has two items (for its two windows, one of which is also called "Untitled").

But if I'm only interested in the windows called "Untitled", then I could run this:

```
    tell application "System Events" to get window "Untitled" of ¬
        (every process whose name is "Script Editor")

        --> {window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events", ¬
             window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events"}
```

Just a single list this time, with my two seemingly-identical windows.

Distinguishing between them can be done as you hinted at in your original question by using the **unix id** of the application processes:

```
    tell application "System Events" to get [window "Untitled", unix id] of ¬
        (every process whose name is "Script Editor")


        --> {{window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events", ¬
              window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events"}, ¬
             {73822, 73913}}
```

You can also use the processes' **id** property instead of their **unix id**, which has the benefit of being easily referenced if you want to target one of the windows in a single line.  **id** and **unix id** are distinct properties, and unique:

```
    tell application "System Events" to get [id, unix id] of ¬
        (processes whose name is "Script Editor")

        --> {{42006541, 42100772}, {73822, 73913}}
```

So I can target a specific window of a specific instance like this:

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        get window "Untitled" of process id 42006541

    --> window "Untitled" of application process "Script Editor" of application "System Events"
```

Comment: Setting the position of a window of a particular instance of your application is done like so: `set position of window "Untitled" of process id 42006541 to {39, 578}`

Comment: It works, Thanks so much! By the way, where can I learn more about AppleScript ?:)

Comment: I presume you've come across the [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) ?  That's what I use.  And also by going through AppleScript posts on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript) and [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applescript).  Otherwise, the best way is always to learn by doing.  Devise a project, do it, and google as you come across things you don't know how to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm attempting to understand what you're trying to achieve, but it is difficult given lack of clear context and knowing where those code snippets have been taken from and how they're being used.

However, I'm answering on my assumption that you have two (or more) windows with the same **name** or title, and wish to know how to isolate **one** of these windows in order to set its position.

Proceeding along this basis, you can use AppleScript to reference windows not only by their title (name), but also by a property called the window **id**.

Firstly, don't use *System Events* for this.  Send your commands directly to the application in question using `tell application "MyApplication" to...`

So, for example, I have two open *Finder* windows both called "Pictures".  But when I run this:

```
    tell application "Finder" to get every window
```

it returns this:

```
    {Finder window id 10557 of application "Finder",
     Finder window id 10786 of application "Finder"}
```

Get the properties of one of these windows like this:

```
    tell application "Finder" to get properties of window id 10557
```

A useful property in this list is **index**: this determines the front-to-back order of the windows, with **index** 1 being the front window, and **index** 2 being the one behind it, and so on.

You can isolate the window you want by choosing any of these properties, and setting its position like this:

```
    tell application "Finder" to set position of window id 10557 to {39, 578}
```

or like this:

```
    tell application "Finder" to set position of window index 1 to {39, 578}
```

Bear in mind that a window's **index** will change according to which is at the front at any given time.  However, the **id** will remain unique and the same, until the window is closed and re-opened, at which point it gets issued a new **id**.

It may also be helpful to know the **id** (which is an integer) will have a value that tells you the order in which the windows were created: the window created most recently will have an **id** of greater numeric value than those that came into existence before it.

Comment: You got I want, very close, I open application with "open -n myApplication.app"  The command `get every window                               
         ` get an error`tell application "myApplication"
       get every window
  --> error number -1708`   Finder is only one app has multi windows, but not fit for my case

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand what it is you want.  `open -n` runs separate instances of the same application...I think I understand a bit better now.  Do you want to get all the windows belonging to each instance of your application ?

Comment: Yes,that's I want to do! I can get pid,but it seems useless.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: No, it's easy.  I'm writing an answer for you now.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a  `tell (first process whose unix id is someID)` block.

Here's an example:

```
set thePosition to {39, 578}
tell application "System Events"
    set pidList to the unix id of (processes whose name contains "MyApplication")

    repeat with someID in pidList -- loop 
        tell (first process whose unix id is someID)
            set position of window "MyApplication Window" to thePosition
        end tell
        set item 1 of thePosition to (item 1 of thePosition) + 200 -- add 200 to the left (for the next window)
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: It would be sublime if one were able to specify distinct values for position in this one line of code: `tell application "System Events" to set position of windows of every process whose name is "MyApplication Window" to {0,0}`  As it is, it just sets them all to the same position.

Comment: I opened multi same application by cmd line 'open -n application.app` . Got error                                                                                                 
     `tell application "System Events"
 get unix id of every process whose name contains "application"
  --> {4125, 4131, 4134, 4137}
 set position of window "application" of process 1 whose unix id = 4125 to {39, 578}
  --> error number -1728 from window "application" of process 1 whose unix id = 4125`

Comment: See my new answer for, what I hope, is now the solution to your problem.